# What is the meaning of "The smartest way to graduate and business school"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I browsed to [The GRE Tests](https://www.ets.org/gre/)  website and saw this sentence on the homepage which I did not understand what it means.

> The smartest way to graduate and business school

What does it mean?

Comment: This is a bit tricky to parse because "graduate" can be a noun (one who had finished school), a verb (to finish school) or an adjective (a type of higher education). I initially tried to read that as a verb which made no sense, but it does make sense as an adjective applied to school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smartest path to Graduate School and to Business School.

Does this help :)?

And thanks for having posted a link to the original site. Reading it in its original context with the original formatting had actually helped.

Comment: Yes, the context given by the link helped a lot!  But the web author phrased it poorly to begin with.  Many will wonder what they mean.  It would have been much clearer if they had stated, "The GRE General Test is your smartest path to either Graduate School or to Business School." As it stands, it is both unclear and uses poor grammar.